# How can I control an existing remote shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, networking, vnc

On my remote machine, an xterm/shell has been created (by another process). I have full access to that shell through VNC. But really I would like to be using a text mode shell on my local machine.

How can I control the existing remote shell from a local one?  I can't create a new shell, that's the point.  But I have non-privileged access to the existing remote shell.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is doable in your situation but you could run `screen bash` (or whichever other shell is your preference) and then `screen -x` in some other unrelated shell to connect to the screen you created.

Comment: can you run ssh? if so, and you still really want to use the existing shell, start screen using vnc in that shell, then from ssh you can screen -x as suggested by adam zalcman.

Answer (score 5):

You should start the shells in [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) so they can be easily reattached in a new terminal.

With `screen` this is done with the following steps:

1. Start the shell somewhere (e.g. in VNC):

   `screen -S myshell`
2. Reattach the shell somewhere else (e.g. a new terminal with SSH):

   `screen -x myshell`

While the methods above are highly recommended, they are not sufficient for controlling an *existing* shell. For that you are going to need some additional tricks.

One way to reattach an existing shell (that wasn't launched with `screen` or `tmux`) is to use [`reptyr`](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr).

From `reptyr`'s [website](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr):

> reptyr is a utility for taking an existing running program and attaching it to a new terminal. Started a long-running process over ssh, but have to leave and don't want to interrupt it? Just start a screen, use reptyr to grab it, and then kill the ssh session and head on home.

You can simply use the process id (PID) and tell reptyr to reattach it:

```
reptyr PID
```