# open a already running process

Tags: linux, rhel

I have 64-bit RHEL 2.6.18-238.el5 running. I access the machine through vpn. I started an application via terminal and while application was running there was disconnection in vpn which closed my terminal. Upon reconnecting to vpn when I opened the terminal I could see that my application is still running ,checked using `ps -ef` command. Now how can I continue using my application in the terminal. Is there any way to access that running application in the terminal? Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a habit of starting [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) as soon as you login in a remote box.

You might want to give [retty](http://pasky.or.cz//dev/retty/) a try, but keep in mind that your chances to regain control of your application are minimal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `screen` tool for situations like this.

First install the screen tool. Then type `screen` and run the application. If the VPN is disconnected, Log in to the server again and type `screen -ls`.

It will list available screen sessions. 
To connect to a screen session type `screen -r <session_name>`. From there you can continue from the last disconnected position.

Answer (score 1):

It's a recurring question here. See

- [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)
- [How can I control an existing remote shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45762/how-can-i-control-an-existing-remote-shell)
- [How to screen'ize already running session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/how-to-screenize-already-running-session)
- [How can I switch between ttys without using screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/how-can-i-switch-between-ttys-without-using-screen)
- [is it possible to run job in foreground after user logout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49946/is-it-possible-to-run-job-in-foreground-after-user-logout)
- [Is it possible to transfer a running process to your terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9534/is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-running-process-to-your-terminal)
- [Is it possible to detach a process started from one ssh session using another ssh session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22473/is-it-possible-to-detach-a-process-started-from-one-ssh-session-using-another-ss)
- [view stdout for another pts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/view-stdout-for-another-pts)
- [How to attach terminal to detached process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process)